# iPhone: add badge to icons internal to my app

Tags: iphone, icons, badge

I am trying to add badges to the icons in my app. e.g. in the facebook app, in the home page the number of pending requests is shown on the requests icon.

Can someone provide any links/ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,
V

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to do this.  You can overlay a UILabel over the icon (which may be a UIView or UIImageView).  YOu can put another view on top of the icon, and draw the text right into that view.  Or make your icon view be a subclass of UIView, and when you get called to draw, you draw the icon and the number.

Plus, you may want to play with blend modes, shadow, masking, etc., in order to create something that is visually attractive.

I'd probably start with reading more about [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/drawingwithquartz2d.pdf), if you haven't already.  The rest is just how you wire it all up.

And some other links:

http://scientificninja.com/development/numeric-badges-on-the-iphone
http://th30z.netsons.org/2009/03/qt4-drawing-notification-badges/
[alt text http://th30z.netsons.org/wp-content/uploads/qtdrawbadges.png](http://th30z.netsons.org/wp-content/uploads/qtdrawbadges.png)